# Fast nearest power of 2 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, double, bit-manipulation, ieee-754

Is there any faster alternative to the following expression:

```
Math.pow(2,Math.floor(Math.log(x)/Math.log(2)))
```

That is, taking the closest (smaller) integer power of 2 of a double? I have such expression in a inner loop. I suspect it could be much faster, considering one could just take the mantissa from the IEEE 754 representation of the double.

Comment: Why dont you hardcode the value of log 2?, or is that too variable?

Comment: Ah, I can do that, of course. But I'm still taking a log, then dividing, then taking a floor, then taking a power of 2. That is too much already, when the information is all there already on the double itself! If I just could cast...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466204/rounding-off-to-nearest-power-of-2

Comment: I've read the whole thread already actually... most of its answers treats integers and mostly depends on C hacks which aren't available on JS...

Comment: That expression will not always work for doubles near powers of two. For example, try x=35184372088831.9 (just below 2^45). Your expression returns 2^45, not 2^44.

Comment: You can access mantissa & exponent of a JavaScript number using ArrayBuffer and typed arrays, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17156580/1647737 - however it might not be fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: the fastest is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916422/236062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is also a branchless 32 bit version which is **the fastest** (9x) (on cellphones even more!) as of now.
It can also be scaled to 64 or 128 bits adding 1 or two lines:

```
x = x | (x >> 64);
x = x | (x >> 128);
```

on my computer:

```
2097152,blpo2: 118 ms **FASTEST**
2097152,nearestPowerOf2: 973 ms
2097152,pow2floor: 2033 ms
```

on my phone:

```
2097152,blpo2: 216 ms **FASTEST**
2097152,nearestPowerOf2: 1259 ms
2097152,pow2floor: 2904 ms
```

```js
function blpo2(x) {
  x = x | (x >> 1);
  x = x | (x >> 2);
  x = x | (x >> 4);
  x = x | (x >> 8);
  x = x | (x >> 16);
  x = x | (x >> 32);
  return x - (x >> 1);
}

function pow2floor(v) {
  var p = 1;
  while (v >>= 1) {
    p <<= 1;
  }
  return p;
}

function nearestPowerOf2(n) {
  return 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(n);
}

function runner(fn, val) {
  var res;
  var st = new Date().getTime()
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    res = fn(val);
  }
  dt = new Date().getTime() - st;
  return res + "," + fn.name + ": " + dt + " ms"
}

var source = 3000000;

console.log(runner(blpo2, source), "**FASTEST**")
console.log(runner(nearestPowerOf2, source))
console.log(runner(pow2floor, source))
```

Comment: If JS is converting input to integer within the function, then it may be actually even faster for some "directly bitwise representable" (23 bit) double-precision values of integers.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik the first ">>"  automatically converts it to integer from then on is always an integer.

Answer (score 22):

Making use of ES6's [Math.clz32(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) to count leading zeros of a 32-bit integer:

```js
// Compute nearest lower power of 2 for n in [1, 2**31-1]:
function nearestPowerOf2(n) {
  return 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(n);
}

// Examples:
console.log(nearestPowerOf2(9));  // 8
console.log(nearestPowerOf2(33)); // 32
```

Comment: Should be very fast in theory, but I didn't test yet.

Comment: But beware the polyfill at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) .  It says clz32(8) is 29 when it should be 28, so if used in this nearestPowerOf2 implementation, you'll get nearestPowerOf2(8) = 4.

Comment: the fastest is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916422/236062  8 times faster on Pc 6 times faster on my cellphone :D

Answer (score 7):

Here's another alternative, with benchmarks. While both seems to be comparable, I like being able to floor or ceil.

```js
function blpo2(x) {
  x = x | (x >> 1);
  x = x | (x >> 2);
  x = x | (x >> 4);
  x = x | (x >> 8);
  x = x | (x >> 16);
  x = x | (x >> 32);
  return x - (x >> 1);
}

function pow2floor(v) {
  var p = 1;
  while (v >>= 1) {
    p <<= 1;
  }
  return p;
}

function pow2ceil(v) {
  var p = 2;
  while (v >>= 1) {
    p <<= 1;
  }
  return p;
}

function MATHpow2(v) {
  return Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log(v) / Math.log(2)))
}


function nearestPowerOf2(n) {
   return 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(n);
}

 function runner(fn, val) {
  var res;
  var st = new Date().getTime()
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    fn(val);
  }
  return (new Date().getTime() - st)
}

var source = 300000;

var a = runner(pow2floor, source);
console.log("\n--- pow2floor ---");
console.log(" result: " + pow2floor(source));
console.log(" time: " + a + " ms");

var b = runner(MATHpow2, source);
console.log("\n--- MATHpow2 ---");
console.log(" result: " + MATHpow2(source));
console.log(" time: " + b + " ms");

var b = runner(nearestPowerOf2, source);
console.log("\n--- nearestPowerOf2 ---");
console.log(" result: " + nearestPowerOf2(source));
console.log(" time: " + b + " ms");

var b = runner(blpo2, source);
console.log("\n--- blpo2 ---");
console.log(" result: " + blpo2(source));
console.log(" time: " + b + " ms");

// pow2floor: 1631 ms
// MATHpow2: 13942 ms
// nearestPowerOf2: 937 ms
// blpo2 : 919 ms   **WINNER**
```

Comment: I rewrote the runner and used a bigger number. differences are now more visible.

Comment: but the fastest is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916422/236062

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you would need an equivalent of the C function `frexp`. The best I've been able to find is in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sx570amp/1/), and its code uses `Math.pow`.

There are a couple of alternatives you could benchmark, using real data, along with your current attempt:

1. Starting at 1.0, multiply repeatedly by 2.0 until it is greater than or equal to the input, then multiply by 0.5 until it is less than or equal to the input. You would need special handling for values at the ends of the double range.
2. Store an ascending value array of all the exact powers of two in the double range, and do a binary search.

The first one is likely to be fastest if your data is typically close to 1.0. The second one requires up to 11 conditional branches.

Comment: very wrong... I found the fastest :D https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916422/236062

Answer (score 0):

Without ES6...

```js
x=Math.floor(Math.random()*500000); //for example
nearestpowerof2=2**(x.toString(2).length-1);
console.log(x,">>>",nearestpowerof2);
```

In other words: the result is 2 to the power of the length of the binary representation of the number subtracted by 1.

Answer (score 0):

And another way (this one is slow but it's fun to code recursive ones):

```js
function calc(n, c) {
  c = c || 0;
  n = n >> 1;
  return (n > 0) ? calc(n, c + 1) : 2 ** c;
}

console.log(calc(345367));
console.log(calc(34536));
console.log(calc(3453));
console.log(calc(345));
console.log(calc(34));
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is another.

```js
function nP2(n) {
  return 1 << Math.log2(n);
}

console.log(nP2(345367));
console.log(nP2(34536));
console.log(nP2(3453));
console.log(nP2(345));
console.log(nP2(34));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh and I forgot the one-liner:

```js
a=3764537465
console.log(2**~~Math.log2(a))
```

In other words, here we raise 2 to the power of the rounded logarithm in base 2 of the number. But alas, this is 140 times slower than the winner: blpo2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916422/236062