# javascript converting scientific notation, how to determine the number after power of 10

Tags: javascript, numbers

If I type a number in the browser console the result is:

```
1000000000000000000000 --> 1e+21
```

```
0.00000000003453 --> 3.453e-11
```

I want to determine the number after `e`. In this example, the number is `21` or `-11`

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383593/extracting-the-exponent-and-mantissa-of-a-javascript-number Maybe this can help you.

Comment: What should smaller numbers give you? For example, should 123 give `123` or `2`?

Comment: Thanks @Marty, I see the someone use `toExponential()` in this thread. And this is what I want to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the number to a string using `.toExponential()` and then split based on `e` and get the last element (which would be your number) like so:

```js
const getExp = n =>
  +(n.toExponential().split('e').pop())

console.log(getExp(1000000000000000000000)) // 21
console.log(getExp(0.00000000003453)); // -11
console.log(getExp(0.000324)); // -4
```

Comment: It works for really long number like that. If the number is 0.000324 it doesn't work. Maybe javascript has some way to convert it. btw, it works for my case. Thanks, you're clever!

Comment: @MattNguyen you could use `toExponential()` to make it work for smaller numbers (I've edited my answer now)

Comment: Wow, I think it's perfect answer for me